# What is correct in this sentence "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct:

> My current address and telephone number **is**:

or

> My current address and telephone number **are**:

Answer (score 2):

I think ARE is the correct verb, [this explanation](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) works in this case:

> Use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by
>   and.
>
> Example: A car and a bike are my means of transportation.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with ab2 - I think this is one of those situations when it can be either, depending on how you parse the sentence.

Your details could either be (1) two separate objects, or (2) a compound object:

> 1. My [current address] and [telephone number] are:
> 2. My [current address and telephone number] is:

Comment: I hate to disagree with an animal lover, but the compound object doesn't work well this case, unless they are bundled in the term "my contact information" is....."